# How to manually match cells that aren't matched by left_join?

Tags: r, left-join, tidyverse

I'm using the tidyverse package in R to match two dataframes by the name of their municipalities. While the majority of my observations are matched, the remainder observations aren't matched due to slight differences in their names ("Sao Joao Del-Rey" and "Sao Joao Del Rey", for example). Is there a way I can specify these municipalities in the left_join function (or other function) so as to also match them?
As an example, I made a reproducible example where the cities of "Rio de Janeiro" and "Paris" have slight differences in the second dataframe. Assuming that I have a list of matches L = ["Rio de Janeiro" = "Rio de-Janeiro", "Paris" = "Pariss"), how can I tell R to also match these cells? Thanks in advance.

````
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(municipalities = c('New York', 'London', 'Shangai', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Paris'),
                crimes = c(5, 7, 8, 4, 6))
df2 <- data.frame(municipalities = c('New York', 'London', 'Shangai', 'Rio de-Janeiro', 'Pariss'),
                 GDP = c(45, 56, 67, 78, 89))

df3 <- df1 %>% left_join (df2, by = 'municipalities')
``` R
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is a fuzzy join based on distance method

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_left_join(df1, df2, by = 'municipalities') %>%
       transmute(municipalities = municipalities.x, crimes, GDP)
```

-output

```
#  municipalities crimes GDP
#1       New York      5  45
#2         London      7  56
#3        Shangai      8  67
#4 Rio de Janeiro      4  78
#5          Paris      6  89
```

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzy join

Or clean the data before the join.  In your reprx you will replace all '-' with a space. Not unreasonable when one data set added a - or space etc.

Fixing Pariss (typo) harder without the fuzzy if the incoming data is subject to poorly validated human entry especially if that can keep happening.

You obviously need to be aware of the risk of fuzzy joining things it should not.   I once turned up in the wrong village because Google listed them the wrong way round (one had a double R the other a single)